# How would one stop reloaddata from refreshing the page?

Tags: xcode, swift, reloaddata

So I figured out why my page kept refreshing, calling        self.tableView.reloadData() forced the page to refresh, as when I changed it to self.tableView.reloadInputViews(), the scrolling stopped.

The problem is that there is no visible increase in digits when a button invoking the latter method is pressed, one has to refresh the entire page to see it. Is there a way to have the functions of reloadData, without having the page scroll each time the button is clicked?

Code for reference,

```
@IBAction func topButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
    object.incrementKey("count")
    object.saveInBackground()
    self.tableView.reloadData()


}


@IBAction func bottomButton(sender: AnyObject) {


    let hitPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let hitIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(hitPoint)
    let object = objectAtIndexPath(hitIndex)
    object.incrementKey("count", byAmount: -1)
    object.saveInBackground()
    self.tableView.reloadInputViews()


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to same page after successful  submit